# Unmanaged Exports (DllExport for .NET) and MSBuild error

Tags: msbuild, managed, nuget-package, dllexport

I've installed Nuget package "Unmanaged Exports (dllExport for .NET). This works fine using MS Visual Studio 2010.

Using MSBuild (Windows SDK v7.1) I get an error `Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.`

Any idea how this can be solved?

**Partial MSBuild output:**

```
MethodDeclarationParserAction: Found method: HSAdapter.HSAdapter..method public hidebysig static void  'CreateHSAdapterInstance'([out] class 'HSAdapter'.'IHSAdapter'&  marshal( interface ) 'instance') cil managed
MethodPropertiesParserAction: Removing RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportAttribute from HSAdapter.HSAdapter.CreateHSAdapterInstance
DeleteExportAttributeParserAction: Adding .vtentry:0 .export:CreateHSAdapterInstance
Parse IL: Deleting unused reference to RGiesecke.DllExport.Metadata.
Parse IL: Parsing 1676 lines of IL took 51 ms.
D:\HS4\packages\UnmanagedExports.1.2.4.23262\tools\RGiesecke.DllExport.targets(42,5): error : Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
at RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportNotifier.Notify(Int32 severity, String code, String fileName, Nullable`1 startPosition, Nullable`1 endPosition, String message, Object[] values) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\DllExportNotifier.cs:line 135
at RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportNotifier.Notify(Int32 severity, String code, String message, Object[] values) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\DllExportNotifier.cs:line 119
at RGiesecke.DllExport.Parsing.DllExportNotifierWrapper.Notify(Int32 severity, String code, String message, Object[] values) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\Parsing\DllExportNotifierWrapper.cs:line 41
at RGiesecke.DllExport.Parsing.IlAsm.RunLibTool(CpuPlatform cpu, String fileName, String directory) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\Parsing\ILAsm.cs:line 212
at RGiesecke.DllExport.Parsing.IlAsm.RunCore(CpuPlatform cpu, String fileName, String ressourceParam, String ilSuffix) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\Parsing\ILAsm.cs:line 186
at RGiesecke.DllExport.Parsing.IlAsm.Run(String outputFile, String ilSuffix, CpuPlatform cpu) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\Parsing\ILAsm.cs:line 123
at RGiesecke.DllExport.Parsing.IlAsm.ReassembleFile(String outputFile, String ilSuffix, CpuPlatform cpu) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\Parsing\ILAsm.cs:line 75
at RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportWeaver.RunIlAsm(IlAsm ilAsm) in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\DllExportWeaver.cs:line 151
at RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportWeaver.Run() in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport\DllExportWeaver.cs:line 81
at RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild.ExportTaskImplementation`1.Execute() in d:\Work\Libraries\RGiesecke.DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport.MSBuild\ExportTaskImplementation.cs:line 243
Done Building Project "D:\HS4\HSAdapter\HSAdapter.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just run into the same problem. The RGiesecke.DllExport.targets file references $(DevEnvDir), which won't be defined in the environment you're running msbuild in (but will be from within Visual Studio). I took the quick and dirty approach of adding a system-wide environment variable on the build server (set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\") to work around it, as I was in a hurry.

Comment: Can you explain better how you resolved this problem?

Comment: I can try, but I'm not sure which part is unclear. I added a Windows system variable named "DevEnvDir" with the value "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\". Windows system variables can be set through Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variables.